# Display text dependant on dropdownmenu choice in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter/Dart and I am trying to figure out how I can display something in a title:text dependant on the value of dropdown-menu choice. I have created a ListTile with a DropDownButton which has items stored as Strings. I want to display a number dependant on the string chosen in the DropDownButton. Can I read the value from the setState, and output a value based on that string? Or is there a better way to do this? I've been googling for about 2 hours and can't seem to understand it.

```
class _BarneAnestesiState extends State<BarneAnestesi> {

String Alder;
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    List<Widget> containers = [

      Container(

        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Scaffold(

          body: new Column(
            children: <Widget> [


     new ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.baby_changing_station),
                title: new DropdownButton(
                  hint: Alder == null
                      ? Text('Dropdown')
                      : Text(
                    Alder,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  isExpanded: true,
                  iconSize: 30.0,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  items: ['Nyfødt', '2 mnd.', '1 år', '2 år', '4 år', '7 år'].map(
                        (val) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: val,
                        child: Text(val),
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(
                          () {
                        Alder = val;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                )),


              new ListTile(
                title: new Text(), //I want to display it here. F.eks. 2mnd. should display 3,5mm
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is but here are what I can think about:

- To reference a variable just use its name, and here you have to check for nullity so you can use [the ?? operator](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators)
- To display a number then a string you can use dart [String interpolation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings) which will lead you to do `'$title:$text`
- Note that [variable should use the lowerCamelCase naming](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#names), not UpperCamelCase. So in your code `Alder` should be `alder`

Finally, here is your code with all of this together. This might not be exactly what you want but you should be able to expand on this.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: BarneAnestesi(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BarneAnestesi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BarneAnestesiState createState() => _BarneAnestesiState();
}

class _BarneAnestesiState extends State<BarneAnestesi> {
  String alder;
  final List<String> items = ['Nyfødt', '2 mnd.', '1 år', '2 år', '4 år', '7 år'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.baby_changing_station),
              title: new DropdownButton(
                hint: alder == null
                    ? Text('Dropdown')
                    : Text(
                  alder,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                isExpanded: true,
                iconSize: 30.0,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                items: items.map(
                      (val) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: val,
                      child: Text(val),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(
                        () {
                      alder = val;
                    },
                  );
                },
              )),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text(
                (alder == 'Nyfødt') ? 'Anything for Nyfødt' :
                (alder == '2 mnd.') ? 'Anything for 2 mnd.' :
                (alder == '1 år') ? 'Anything for 1 år' :
                (alder == '2 år') ? 'Anything for 2 år' :
                (alder == '4 år') ? 'Anything for 4 år' :
                (alder == '7 år') ? 'Anything for 7 år' : ''
            ), //I want to display it here. F.eks. 2mnd. should display 3,5mm
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but I am still having some issues. I am already able to display what I want in the DropDownButton, but I am unable to display what I want in the ListTile below it dependant on what the DropDownButton is displaying. If the DropDownButton has index 1 activated, or simply the string "2 mnd." I am trying to make the ListTile title display f.ex. 3.5mm. Also thank you for the other advices you gave on codingpractices (lowerCamelCase).

Comment: @Veritaas have a look at the update. Still not sure it's what you want but that's something. If it's not what you want maybe try explaining more.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted! Had no idea I could do it that easy, simply check what the alder-string is, and dependant on what the string is, I can output a predefined text. That was really helpful, thanks!

Comment: Welcom to the beauty of declarative programming (https://ui.dev/imperative-vs-declarative-programming/)